# Regex match word between special characters

Tags: regex

I have need to get the word between `.` and `)`

I am using this: `\..*\)`

But if there is more than one `.` I am getting the first `.` to `)` instead of the last `.` to `)`.

E.g:

```
abc.def.ghi.jkl.mymodname(Object sender, CompletedEventArgs e)
```

I am getting :

```
def.ghi.jkl.mymodname(Object sender, CompletedEventArgs e)
```

I want:

```
mymodname(Object sender, CompletedEventArgs e)
```

Any pointers?
I'm new to regex, as you can see...

Comment: Which language are you using to identify the pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be explicit. If you don't want any dots between your starting dot and the closing parenthesis, you can specify this:

```
\.[^.]*\)
```

`[^.]` is a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), meaning "any character except a dot". That way, only non-dots are allowed to match after the dot.

And if you don't want the leading dot to be a part of the match (but do want it to be present before the start of the match), you can use a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\.)[^.]*\)
```

This works in nearly all regex engines except for JavaScript and Ruby (until version 1.8), both of which do not support lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

try `.[a-bA-B0-9,(]*)`
I did not check it but I think something like that works
or you can also use somthing

Answer (score 0):

in PHP

```
$a='abc.def.ghi.jkl.mymodname(Object sender, CompletedEventArgs e)';
$p='/.*\.(.*?\))/';
preg_match($p,$a,$m);
```

now look at `$m[1]`

Other languages analogous

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want to do is strip off everything to the last dot.

In shell:

```
    sed 's/.*\.//'
```

or in PHP

```
    preg_replace('/^.*\./', '', $foo);
```

Beware of stray dots within your method, though.

```
def.ghi.jkl.mymodname(Object sender, "Some text.", CompletedEventArgs e)
```

For this, you might want:

```
    sed -r 's/.*\.([a-zA-Z]\()/\1/'
```

or something equivalent.